# How to delete document by _id using MongoDB and Jade (Express.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have successfully set up a database using mongodb, and I have managed to add new entries to my collection. However, when I use a similar method to delete, nothing happens.

**Express.js code**

```
router.post('/deleteproject', function(req, res) {
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/plugd';

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Unable to connect to server", err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to server');

        var collection = db.collection('projects');

        collection.remove(
            {_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(req.body)}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                res.redirect("thelist");
            }
            db.close();
        });
    }
});
```

});

**Jade code**

```
h2.
ul
    Projects
    each project, i in projectlist
        #project_list_item
            a(href='#') #{project.owner} - #{project.project} 
            p #{project.ref1} 
            p #{project.ref2} 
            p #{project.ref3}
            form#form_delete_project(name="deleteproject", method="post", action="/deleteproject")
            input#input_name(type="hidden", placeholder="", name="_id", value="#{project._id}")
            button#submit_project(type="submit") delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my fix for deleting data from a mongodb collection using a router in express.js.

**Express.js**

```
    router.post('/deleteproject', function(req, res) {
       var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
       var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
       var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/app';

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err){
            console.log('Unable to connect to server', err);

        } else {
            console.log("Connection Established");

            var collection = db.collection('projects');

            collection.remove({_id: new ObjectId(req.body._id)}, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    res.redirect("thelist");
                }
                db.close();                                 
            });
        }   
    });         
});
```

**Jade code**

```
extends layout

block content

    h2.
        Projects
    ul
        each project, i in projectlist
            #project_list_item
                a(href='#') #{project.owner} - #{project.project} 
                p #{project.ref1} 
                p #{project.ref2} 
                p #{project.ref3}
            form#form_delete_project(name="deleteproject", method="post", action="/deleteproject")
                input#input_name(type="hidden", placeholder="", name="_id", value="#{project._id}")
                button#submit_project(type="submit") delete
```

The jade file is rendering to a page called 'thelist' that lists each item in the collection.

The form section handles the delete function for each item in the list.

This works for me as long as I keep Jade's indents happy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works :

```
router.post('/deleteproject', function(req, res) {
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/plugd';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
if (err) {
    console.log("Unable to connect to server", err);
} else {
    console.log('Connected to server');

    var collection = db.collection('projects');

    collection.remove(
        {_id: req.body}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect("thelist");
        }
        db.close();
    });
}
});
});
```

Since you're on MongoDB's Node.js Native Driver, you don't need to marshall _id inside ObjectId. You can directly specify the _id as `string`

Comment: I updated my express code and still got no response. I found that the error was in my jade file. I had to unindent the form line. However, NOW that the form is executing, I am getting 404 Not Found error for /deleteproject. Any ideas??